# recursive function with delete nodes of tree

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I need to know how to recursive this function so that it looks for the grandchildren of the parent node and so on, for now, how does this one bring me only the direct children?

```js
const data=[{id_nodo:1,padre:null},{id_nodo:2,padre:1},{id_nodo:3,padre:1},{id_nodo:4,padre:1},{id_nodo:5,padre:3},{id_nodo:6,padre:2},{id_nodo:7,padre:3},{id_nodo:8,padre:null},{id_nodo:9,padre:8},{id_nodo:10,padre:null},{id_nodo:11,padre:10}];

let toDeleteList = [];
function deleteNode(id){
  toDeleteList.push(id);
  data.filter(d =>d.padre === id)
    .forEach(child=>{
      toDeleteList.push(child.id_nodo);
      deleteNode(child.id_nodo);
    });
  return data.filter(d=>!toDeleteList.includes(d.id_nodo));
}
const result = deleteNode(1);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Does that code not work as expected and you want someone to alter it?  Or it does, but you want someone to explain it to you?

Comment: If the code works but I need to modify it so that it also detects the grandchildren of the node id that has the null parent property because now, like this, the code only detects the direct children of that node.

Comment: What do you mean? If you call `deleteNode(1)`, the returned array does not contain node with id `1`, nor any of its children, nor any of its grandchildren, nor any of its descendants.  Maybe I don't understand what you are looking for.  Please consider modifying the code in this question so as to constitute a [mcve] which, when dropped into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play), clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing, with actual and expected output and how they differ.

Comment: children are formed if the node_id property is equal to the parent property of some of the nodes in the array
for example
in this array, the root node would be 1 because it has the parent property, its direct child would be 2 because the parent property of id_nodo 2 is 1 and id_nodo 3 is its grandson because it is a direct child of the id_nodo that has in its parent property the number 2                                                                                                              
 `const data=[{id_nodo:1,padre:null},{id_nodo:2,padre:1},{id_nodo:3,padre:2}]`

Comment: The problem in this example is if I pass the number 1 as a parameter to the function, it will bring me the node_id 2 but it will not bring me the node_id 3 and I need him to bring me his grandson as well.

Comment: I honestly do not understand you; instead of describing the situation with *words*, could you please make a [mcve] with *code*?  The code should do the talking here: [change this example](https://tsplay.dev/WP58Jw) so that something is actually *wrong*.  If `result` is not what you expect, write code which demonstrates that fact.  Please consult the guidelines for [ask] and what constitutes a [mcve] for more information.

Comment: if that code doesn't work as expected and I need someone to modify it

Comment: I’m sorry but I cannot help you. Perhaps someone else will come along who understands what you’re trying to do without the aid of a [mcve].  Good luck.

Comment: Hi Pancho.  When you run `const result = deleteNode(1); console.log(result);`  You get the nodes 8,9,10, and 11.  All of the others get deleted because they are children, grandchilden, etc. of the deleted node 1.  What is the outcome that you are expecting?  Are you trying to *select* nodes instead of *delete* nodes?

Comment: Does it make more sense broken into steps? https://tsplay.dev/N9AQqN